# how to get facebook saved content by Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had collection some things in facebook(https://www.facebook.com/saved/),i want to get the content by Graph API,but i can't found API in Graph API document.

[image]

Does Facebook provide this API , if so, please tell me what it is,thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you searching for (under Android SDK tab): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/

Comment: I tried, but the response were always empty.:{  "data": [  ]}:

Comment: yes,i use this tool to test:https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fsave.saves&version=v2.4

Comment: I've never read "save.saved", but worked with stories on timeline. And the empty result is very likely caused by lack of permissions.

Comment: i selected all permissions in Graph API Explorer tool

Comment: So is it not possible any more?